# Remove the ribbon on add new item

Tags: list, ribbon, custom-form, item

On the "Add new item" option on a list, the new form page has a ribbon attached:

[image]

I want to edit this page into a custom one with more different types of "Save" buttons.

Before I start cranking at this, I want to know if it is possible to remove the ribbon from this page and the default save button and just add my own save buttons with no ribbon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not advisable to start playing with the ribbon like this as it *will* come back to haunt you.  Rather than hiding the Ribbon and adding your own buttons, why don't you simply create a feature to add your own buttons to the current Ribbon?

Here's [a great article](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/customizing-ribbon-part-1-creating-tabs.html) to get you started.